# Application running on WCF .net

Tags: sql, .net, wcf

I have a scenario our application is developed in wcf , we have to select more than 2500 records ( Delivery Notes )and once selected we are using for loop to collect the data parameters of the selected records and inserting to DB for generating a single invoice, this is taking lots of time and some time this is not performing, any suggestions. We are looking out for a reliable and fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SqlBulkCopy class to insert set of records as bulk without inserting one by one executing loop.Here is some useful links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net